# What's the difference between these two jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

With this markup:

```
<div id="e">  
    <div id="f"></div>  
</div>
```

Does [`$('#e > #f')`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant) return the same as [`$('#e #f')`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [parent > child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild) selector will only look for *direct child elements*, while the [`ancestor descendant`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant) will look for any descendant element.

For example, with the following markup:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$('.foo > .bar')` will not find the `.bar` element, while `$('.foo .bar')` does find it because `.foo` isn't direct child from `.bar`, but it is a descendant.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm assuming you meant `$('#e > #f')` and `$('#e #f')`.

In your example, they will both return the same thing. The difference is that `$('#e #f')` would also return a div in this case:

```
<div id="e">
  <div id="g">
    <div id="f"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$('#e > #f')`, on the other hand, would return nothing there, as it only selects elements which are *direct children* of other elements.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, as that is verbatim to what I posted originally. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry- I'm not sure why, I thought you had posted `$('e > f')`. I must have misread.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work, because you don't specify what elements you are looking for. You need to put #e > #f or #e #f to grab by your IDs.

If this were a real scenario, #e > #f will only find children, nothing nested below that. #e #f will grab any id="f" elements, no matter how far nested they may be inside your structure.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, yes they will return the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as there are no `e` or `f` elements in HTML, they will always return empty jQuery objects.

The call `$('#e > #f')` will return the element with `id="f"` if it's a direct decendant of the element with `id="e"`.

The call `$('#e #f')` will return the element with `id=f` if it's somewhere inside the element with `id="e"`.

Edit:
Note: As the question was edited after I answered, the first sentence does not apply to what the question currently looks like.

Comment: Read the first part under 'With this markup:'; then rephrase your first sentence.